# Title bar graphic mangled on nvidia hybrid graphic system

Tags: drivers, nvidia, hybrid-graphics, gpu, titlebar

I'm using ubuntu 13.10 and I'm currently having problems with the title bar on every window I open it looks really bad, here's a pic. Thanks in advance .

[image]

The ubuntu version is 13.10 64-bit, the graphic card is intel hd 4400 (This is a laptop, intel i5 4200-U) which also have a nvidia 740M.

Comment: Missing ton of data. How are we supposed to guess the Ubuntu version, the graphic card, the drivers (proprietary of open source)?

Comment: The ubuntu version is 13.10 64-bit, the graphic card is intel hd 4400 (This is a laptop, intel i5 4200-U) also have a nvidia 740M.

Comment: I have edited the title and the text so that the question is more specific --- this will help you to be found by people with similar problem.

Comment: Suggest that you search/read questions here regarding issues with Nvidia drivers.

Comment: Thanks Rmano ! douggro: I have search some questions here but none of them have shown that problem